# Numpy Append Data to an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a code that will add 2 arrays(element by element) and store them in a 3rd array.

Basic Logic:

```
arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
```

For this, I have created two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`. The result of the sum of arr1 and arr2 is getting appended in an empty array `arr3`.

code:

```
from numpy import append, array, int8


arr1 = array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr2 = array([2,4,6,8,10])

len = max(arr1.size,arr2.size)

arr3 = array([],dtype=int8)

for i in range(len):
    append(arr3,arr1[i]+arr2[i])
    print(arr1[i]+arr2[i])
    print(arr3[i])

print(arr3)
```

In this code, I'm able to refer to elements of arr1 and arr2 and add them, but I'm not able to append the data to arr3.

Can anyone please help me to understand, what is the mistake in the code due to which I'm not able to store the data to arr3?

Comment: that kind of iteration and appending is appropriate for python lists. It is wrong for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
arr3 = arr1 + arr2
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that `append` doesn't mutate the array, but returns a new one. You can simply modify your code like this:

```
for i in range(len):
    arr3 = append(arr3,arr1[i]+arr2[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer @sagi. As I have worked on Java, and I'm learning Python, I'm first trying to write the code without inbuilt functions. If it's possible, can you please suggest a way so that I can the store the result of sum in arr3 without using inbuilt functions

Comment: Mm, I'm not sure I understood.. What is wrong with my example?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer, and for experienced developers this way of adding elements of arrays is great. It's just that this answer is specifically for python for example if I try to write arr3 = arr1 + arr2 in Java, I will get an error. So I'm asking can this program be written without using inbuilt functions like using for loop, so that it can act as bridge between my understanding of Java and Python

Answer (score 0):

First things first

**Do Not Use built-in function name as variable**.

`len` is a built-in function in python.

@sagi's answer is right. Writing the for loop would mean your code is not time-optimized.

But if you still want to understand where your code went wrong, check array shape

```
import numpy as np
arr3 = np.array([],dtype=int8)
print (arr3.shape)
>>> (0,)
```

Maybe you can create an empty array of the same shape as `arr1` or `arr2`. Seems like for your problem they have same dimension.

```
arr3 = np.empty(arr1.shape, dtype=arr1.dtype)
arr3[:] = arr1 + arr2
```

If you are still persisting to use the dreaded `for` loop and `append` then use this--

```
list3 = []
for x, y in zip(arr1, arr2):
   list3.append(x+y)
arr3 = np.asarray(list3)
print(arr3)
>>> array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15])
```

Cheers, good luck!!

Comment: your last example with `np.append` is not right,  It doesn't change `arr3`

Answer (score 0):

This could give indexing errors:

```
max(arr1.size,arr2.size)
```

if the arrays differ, `range` over this would produce index values that are too large for the smaller array.

The straight forward way of summing the 2 arrays is

```
In [79]: arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    ...: arr2 = np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
In [80]: arr1+arr2
Out[80]: array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15])
```

It makes optimal use of the `numpy` array definitions, and is fastest.

If you must iterate (for example because you want to learn from your mistakes), use something like (which is actually better if the inputs are lists, not arrays):

```
In [86]: alist = []
    ...: for x,y in zip(arr1,arr2):
    ...:     alist.append(x+y)
    ...: 
In [87]: alist
Out[87]: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

or better yet as a list comprehension

```
In [88]: [x+y for x,y in zip(arr1,arr2)]
Out[88]: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

I'm using `zip` instead of the `arr1[i]` types of range indexing.  It's more concise, and less likely to produce errors.

`np.append`, despite the name, is **not** a list `append` clone.  Read, if necessary reread, the `np.append` docs.

```
append : ndarray
        A copy of `arr` with `values` appended to `axis`.  Note that
        `append` does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and
        filled.  If `axis` is None, `out` is a flattened array.
```

This does work, but is slower:

```
In [90]: arr3 = np.array([])
    ...: for x,y in zip(arr1,arr2):
    ...:     arr3 = np.append(arr3,x+y)
    ...: 
In [91]: arr3
Out[91]: array([ 3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15.])
```

I would like to remove `np.append`, since it misleads far too many beginners.

Iteration like this is great for lists, but best avoided when working with numpy arrays.  Learn to use the defined numpy operators and methods, and use elementwise iteration only as last resort.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, but it is not appending data to arr3

Comment: My last example does append values to `arr3`, not that I recommend using it.